# How can I output another page "** I'm the new first page**" in/with pdfwebmac.tex (or webmac.tex) before the document?

Tags: tex-core, web

I got it here: [pdfwebmac.tex](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/misc/tex/common/teTeX-1.0.1/lib/texmf/pdftex/plain/misc/pdfwebmac.tex)

It's the hyperlink version of webmac. In principle, the question should also apply to **webmac**. My Tex Live 2019 distribution only contained the webmac.

With `weave tex.web` you get **`tex.tex`** and there you put "pdfwebmac" in the first line:

```
\input pdfwebmac
```

In `pdfwebmac.tex` I tried this in line 176 (** I'm the new first page **):

```
\def\rhead{\.{WEB} OUTPUT} % this running head is reset by starred sections
\def\title{** I'm the new first page **} % an optional title can be set by the user
\def\topofcontents{\centerline{\titlefont\title}
  \vfill} % this material will start the table of contents page
\def\botofcontents{\vfill} % this material will end the table of contents page
```

After:

```
pdftex tex.tex
```

my test string does not appear anywhere in the PDF.

Does anyone know how pdfwebmac works and can explain it or is there documentation?

Comment: In the built `tex.tex` there is `\def\title{\TeX82}` and a different definition of `\topofcontents` is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look down in the built `tex.tex` file and you'll see

```
     84 \def\title{\TeX82}
     85 \def\topofcontents{\hsize 5.5in
     86   \vglue 0pt plus 1fil minus 1.5in
     87   \def\?##1]{\hbox to 1in{\hfil##1.\ }}
     88   }
     89 \def\botofcontents{\vskip 0pt plus 1fil minus 1.5in}
```

(line numbers added for reference).

Comment: Then I now understand a little more again why weave would have to be changed as you mentioned before for my actual goal. Could pdfwebmac make changes to `tex.tex`?

Comment: Well, `tex.tex` calls `\con` in order to typeset the table of contents. You can modify the definition that you find in `pdfwebmac.tex`